# How to get meterId based on given sku/size in Azure

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

Is there a way to map a given Virtual Machine size (like Standard_A0) to a meterId ? I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/resourceskus/list) link but it seems the api doesn't return meterId (even though it's mentioned in the documentation)

Comment: Does this help ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/operator/azure-stack-usage-related-faq?view=azs-2002#managed-disks I couldn't find any API call as well..

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately it doesn't help. I am looking for a mapping like, Standatd_A0 VM size to meterId.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was posted in the feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/906772-cost-management/suggestions/34206586-add-meter-id-as-part-of-the-rest-apis-that-list-re), and the Azure Cost Management team replied `UNPLANNED`.

[image]